# How can I put a JCheckbox on a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, jcheckbox

How can I put a `JCheckbox` or a `JButton` on a specific row and column of a `JTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about a button, but here is a working example to put a checkbox:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String [] {"CheckMe", "Value"}) {
                                public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                                  switch (c) {
                                    case 0: return Boolean.class;
                                    default: return String.class;
                                  }   
                                } };
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Test");
    frame.add(table);
    model.addRow(new Object [] {true, "This is true"});
    model.addRow(new Object [] {false, "This is false"});
    frame.pack(); frame.validate();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can tell from khachik's answer support for a check box is provided by a table based on the column class of the column.

However, if you only want a check box on a specific row of a specific column then you need to override the getCellRenderer(...) and getCellEditor(...) methods to return the renderer/editor for the given cell. Something like:

```
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
{
    int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

    if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
        return getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class);
    else
        return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you'll have to write a `TableCellRenderer` and a `TableCellEditor`.

You can derive from default swing implementations to make it easier.

In each class, you'll have to override the one method of these interfaces, and in it, check the passed `row` and `column` arguments; if both row and column match your criteria, then return a `JCheckBox` or a `JButton`, otherwise return the `JComponent` returned by the `super` implementation (when using default swing implementations of these interfaces).